# Default Value in react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form, react-select

i have a react-select component which i made compatible with redux-form. My SelectInput component is this:

```
const MySelect = props => (
  <Select
    {...props}
    value={props.input.value}
    onChange={value => props.input.onChange(value)}
    onBlur={() => props.input.onBlur(props.input.value)}
    options={props.options}
    placeholder={props.placeholder}
  />
);
```

and i render it in my component which is a form

```
<div className="select-box__container">
                <Field
                  id="side"
                  name="side"
                  component={SelectInput}
                  options={sideOptions}
                  value="Any"
                  clearable={false}
                  // placeholder="Select Side"
                />
              </div>
```

I've also set initial values to the container so as the state for this component has an initial value and it's working. My problem is that when i render the component the initial value does not show in the selection box and it's empty. Why is this happenning?

Comment: what u r expecting value 'any' should be selected in Select ?

Comment: exactly, i want to test my select with a value any to see if it is rendered with my component but it didn't.

Comment: try this: swap these two lines, instead of `{...props}
    value={props.input.value}` use this: 
    `value={props.input.value} {...props}` in Select component.

Comment: @MayankShukla didnt work

Comment: Any other ideas? I think of editing my selectInput like this <Select
    {...props}
    tempValue={props.input.value}
    {tempValue !== undefined ?
      value={tempValue} :
      value="Any"
    }
    // value={props.input.value}
    onChange={value => props.input.onChange(value)}
    // onBlur={() => props.input.onBlur(props.input.value)}
    options={props.options}
    placeholder={props.placeholder}
    // defaultValue="Any"
  /> but didnt work...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a default value in react-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495696/how-to-set-a-default-value-in-react-select)

Answer (score 4):

What is the shape of your `options`? - commonly it is an array of objects with a value and a label property:

```
[
  { label: "I like", value: "icecream" },
  { label: "Any", value: "Any" }
]
```

You can set the initial `value` prop of react-select by setting it to one of the values in your options array. 
Alternatively, you can as well set it to a non existing option, by giving it an object with a label and a value. The `label` is what is displayed as the `value` of the select. Indeed a little bit confusing, though it makes kind of some sense.

**TL;DR**

`value={{ value: 0, label: 'Any' }}` - will do the trick!

You can as well set the initial value to a value of your options and it will get displayed. Meaning if you have `{ value: "Any", label: "Any" }` in your options `value={'Any'}` would display "Any" in the select.

Hope this works for you!

Comment: My options is an array of objects like this:const sideOptions = [
      { label: 'Any', value: 'Any' },
      { label: 'Buy', value: 'Buy' },
      { label: 'Sell', value: 'Sell' }
];. I want by SelectInput to be label:Any with value Any. I've set value={{ value=0, label='Any' }} but it didn't work finally

Comment: To be more specific should i add initialValue = {props.initialValue } and then in my component initialValue={{label: 'Any, value: 'Any}}?

Comment: sorry for the delayed reply! You can just set `value` prop on react-select to your initial value. There is no `initialValue` prop in react-select. Hope that clears things up for you.

Comment: yea, but this was for react-select 1.x and 2.x.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into a similar issue. The input value field is constantly unset even though it is properly passed. You can either create an `input` object that has a value prop (and all other required props) or use a separate prop `selectedValue` in this case.

```
 <Field
  id="side"
  name="side"
  component={SelectInput}
  options={sideOptions}
  value="Any"
  clearable={false}
  selectedValue={this.props.myvalue}
 />

const MySelect = props => (
  <Select
   {...props}
   value={(props.input.value) ? props.input.value : props.selectedValue}
   onChange={value => props.input.onChange(value)}
   onBlur={() => props.input.onBlur(props.input.value)}
   options={props.options}
   placeholder={props.placeholder}
  />
);
```