# How to set a default value in react-select

Tags: reactjs, default-value, react-select

I have an issue using react-select. I use redux form and I've made my react-select component compatible with redux form. Here is the code:

```
const MySelect = props => (
    <Select
        {...props}
        value={props.input.value}
        onChange={value => props.input.onChange(value)}
        onBlur={() => props.input.onBlur(props.input.value)}
        options={props.options}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        selectedValue={props.selectedValue}
    />
);
```

and here how I render it:

```
<div className="select-box__container">
    <Field
    id="side"
    name="side"
    component={SelectInput}
    options={sideOptions}
    clearable={false}
    placeholder="Select Side"
    selectedValue={label: 'Any', value: 'Any'}
    />
</div>
```

But the problem is that that my dropdown has not a default value as I wish. What I'm doing wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: this is correct: value={props.input.value}. what is the issue you facing?

Comment: My issue is that i want my select to have a defaultValue when i first render it but i can't

Comment: what is value of props.input.value  when it render first?

Comment: That's my problem. How to set it to have a default value?

Comment: what value do you want?

Comment: i want to have a default value = 'Any'

Answer (score 150, accepted):

I guess you need something like this:

```
const MySelect = props => (
<Select
    {...props}
    value = {
       props.options.filter(option => 
          option.label === 'Some label')
    }
    onChange = {value => props.input.onChange(value)}
    onBlur={() => props.input.onBlur(props.input.value)}
    options={props.options}
    placeholder={props.placeholder}
  />
);
```

#EDIT 1 : In the new version

```
const MySelect = props => (
<Select
    {...props}
     options={props.options} 
    onChange = {value => props.input.onChange(value)}
    onBlur={() => props.input.onBlur(props.input.value)}//If needed
    defaultValue={props.defaultValue || 'Select'}
    options={props.options}
    placeholder={props.placeholder}
  />
);
```

Comment: The point in binding with redux/react is so the ui reflects the value of the object in real time. this approach decouples that binding. Consider setting the default value in the reducer.

Comment: @JosephJuhnke check the question first. It is how to set default value.

Comment: `selectedValue` had been changed to `value`. Check docs https://react-select.com/props

Comment: There is `defaultValue` field now in the new version.

Comment: the tricky thing is you need to set the selected object to 'defaultValue' field, instead of the value of the options. e.g. 0,1,2

Comment: i am function with this:   
 value = {eOptions.filter(option=> option.value == this.state.employmentStatus)}
                                                         defaultValue={this.state.employmentStatus}

Comment: @transang this is wrong and very confusing. Setting `value` will indeed set the value... which you won't be able to change anymore (hardly the desired effect). please remove your comment, or define for which versions it should have worked.

Comment: `options={props.options}` is not required once you done `{...props}`

Answer (score 121):

I used the defaultValue parameter, below is the code how I achieved a default value as well as update the default value when an option is selected from the drop-down.

```
<Select
  name="form-dept-select"
  options={depts}
  defaultValue={{ label: "Select Dept", value: 0 }}
  onChange={e => {
              this.setState({
              department: e.label,
              deptId: e.value
              });
           }}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, now i know that defaultValue takes the object instead of just value.

Comment: Not according to React docs or intelisense it doesn't: https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values

Comment: @Alex - (and for anyone here 2 years later), this question was in reference to react-select, a component library. The docs you linked to are in reference to native HTML select elements.

Comment: the trick in the value of defaultValue as is not simple val but takes object instead. Thanks

Answer (score 54):

If you've come here for react-select v2, and still having trouble - version 2 now only accepts an object as `value`, `defaultValue`, etc.

That is, try using `value={{value: 'one', label: 'One'}}`, instead of just `value={'one'}`.

Comment: incomplete. if you set value to that, you cannot change the valuie any longer

Comment: @Toskan - yes, this is one of the principles of ReactJS and one-way data binding, and affects all form elements not just this library. You need to handle the change yourself outside of react if you choose to have a Controlled Component. This answer talks about it and links through to the React Docs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42522515/what-are-react-controlled-components-and-uncontrolled-components

Comment: ok fair enough, so what problem does you solution solve? that is, hard coding a value?

Comment: The case of `{value: 'one', label: 'One'}` given here is merely an example. In your application this would be a variable/prop with an identical structure.

Comment: One way data binding doesn't mean data once set from a prop cannot be changed within the child component if so wishes. Which is exactly what will happen if `defaultValue` is used instead of `value`

Answer (score 13):

I was having a similar error.  Make sure your options have a value attribute.

```
<option key={index} value={item}> {item} </option>
```

Then match the selects element value initially to the options value.

```
<select 
    value={this.value} />
```

Comment: I think this is the best/most elegant solution. Am I correct in thinking that?

Comment: value will not change if do so, you have write onChange function too set change

Comment: This is for a vanilla HTML <select> element, not a react-select <Select>, which is what was question was for. Casing can make all the difference :)

Answer (score 12):

Extending on @isaac-pak's answer, if you want to pass the default value to your component in a prop, you can save it in state in the componentDidMount() lifecycle method to ensure the default is selected the first time.

Note, I've updated the following code to make it more complete and to use an empty string as the initial value per the comment.

```
export default class MySelect extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedValue: '',
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

        this.options = [
            {value: 'foo', label: 'Foo'},
            {value: 'bar', label: 'Bar'},
            {value: 'baz', label: 'Baz'}
        ];

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            selectedValue: this.props.defaultValue,
        })
    }

    handleChange(selectedOption) {
        this.setState({selectedValue: selectedOption.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Select
                value={this.options.filter(({value}) => value === this.state.selectedValue)}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                options={this.options}
            />
        )
    }
}

MySelect.propTypes = {
    defaultValue: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

Comment: I get this: Warning: `value` prop on `select` should not be null. Consider using an empty string to clear the component or `undefined` for uncontrolled components.

Comment: I'm doing the same and I'm getting this warning: `Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type hidden to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa).`

Comment: @AlexVentura I've made my code a little more complete and tested it on my system. I don't get the warning about controlled input. Try updating your code based on my edited response and post back what you find.

Answer (score 8):

Use defaultInputValue props like so:

```
<Select
   name="name"
   isClearable
   onChange={handleChanges}
   options={colourOptions}
   isSearchable="true"
   placeholder="Brand Name"
   defaultInputValue="defaultInputValue"
/>
```

for more reference https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select

Answer (score 5):

As I followed all the answers above, it came to my mind, I should write this.

you have to set the prop **value**, not the **DefaultValue**.
I spent hours by using this, read the documentation, they mentioned to use the DefaultValue, but it is not working.
correct way would be,

```
options=[{label:'mylabel1',value:1},{label:'mylabel2',value:2}]
seleted_option={label:'mylabel1',value:1}

<Select
options={options}
value={selected_option}/>
```

Comment: in this case you can also set the default value as an index of the options <Select options={options} value={options[0]} />

Answer (score 4):

pass `value` object :

```
<Select
                    isClearable={false}
                    options={[
                      {
                        label: 'Financials - Google',
                        options: [
                          { value: 'revenue1', label: 'Revenue' },
                          { value: 'sales1', label: 'Sales' },
                          { value: 'return1', label: 'Return' },
                        ],
                      },
                      {
                        label: 'Financials - Apple',
                        options: [
                          { value: 'revenue2', label: 'Revenue' },
                          { value: 'sales2', label: 'Sales' },
                          { value: 'return2', label: 'Return' },
                        ],
                      },
                      {
                        label: 'Financials - Microsoft',
                        options: [
                          { value: 'revenue3', label: 'Revenue' },
                          { value: 'sales3', label: 'Sales' },
                          { value: 'return3', label: 'Return' },
                        ],
                      },
                    ]}
                    className="react-select w-50"
                    classNamePrefix="select"
                    value={{ value: 'revenue1', label: 'Revenue' }}
                    isSearchable={false}
                    placeholder="Select A Matric"
                    onChange={onDropdownChange}
                  />
```

Comment: For any future readers, this is probably the best and simplest option. The value prop works without redux too.

Answer (score 2):

I just went through this myself and chose to set the default value at the reducer INIT function.

If you bind your select with redux then best not 'de-bind' it with a select default value that doesn't represent the actual value, instead set the value when you initialize the object.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do deep search if you use groups in options:

```
options={[
  { value: 'all', label: 'All' },
  {
    label: 'Specific',
    options: [
      { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
      { value: 'two', label: 'Two' },
      { value: 'three', label: 'Three' },
    ],
  },
]}
```

```
const deepSearch = (options, value, tempObj = {}) => {
  if (options && value != null) {
    options.find((node) => {
      if (node.value === value) {
        tempObj.found = node;
        return node;
      }
      return deepSearch(node.options, value, tempObj);
    });
    if (tempObj.found) {
      return tempObj.found;
    }
  }
  return undefined;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

### Use `defaultValue` instead of `selected`

If you want to hide the value from the menu, use `hidden`:

```
<option defaultValue hidden>
   {'--'}
</option>
{options.map(opt => (
    <option key={opt} value={opt.replaceAll(/[,'!?\s]/gi, '')}>
       {opt}
    </option>
))}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using redux-form and you are using local state for changes then your react-select component might look like this:

```
class MySelect extends Component {

constructor() {
    super()
}

state = {
     selectedValue: 'default' // your default value goes here
}

render() {
  <Select
       ...
       value={this.state.selectedValue}
       ...
  />
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using frequently something like this.

> Default value from props in this example

```
if(Defaultvalue ===item.value) {
    return <option key={item.key} defaultValue value={item.value}>{plantel.value} </option>   
} else {
    return <option key={item.key} value={item.value}>{plantel.value} </option> 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use
`<select value={stateValue}>`. Make sure that the value in `stateValue` is among the options given in the select field.

Answer (score 1):

couple of points:

1. *defaultValue* works for initial render, it will not be updated on sequential render passes. Make sure you are rendering your Select after you have *defaultValue* in hand.
2. *defaultValue* should be defined in form of Object or Array of Objects like this: `{value:'1', label:'Guest'}`, most bulletproof way is to set it as item of options list: `myOptionsList[selectedIndex]`

Answer (score 1):

In `useForm` hook of **React-hook-form** provide `defaultValues` parameter

```
const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    defaultValues: {
      select: { label: "20", value: 20 },
    },
  });
```

> react-select component

```
<Select
     optons={[
        { value: "20", label: "20" },
        { value: "30", label: "30" },
        { value: "25", label: "25" },
      ]}
/>
```

**OR**

provide `defaultValue` attribute to `react-select` component

```
<Select
   defaultValue={{ label: "20", value: 20 }
   optons={[
      { value: "20", label: "20" },
      { value: "30", label: "30" },
      { value: "25", label: "25" },
   ]}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your options are like this

```
var options = [
  { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
  { value: 'two', label: 'Two' }
];
```

Your `{props.input.value}` should match one of the `'value'` in your `{props.options}`

Meaning, `props.input.value` should be either `'one'` or `'two'`

Answer (score 0):

To auto-select the value of in select.

[image]

```
<div className="form-group">
    <label htmlFor="contactmethod">Contact Method</label>
    <select id="contactmethod" className="form-control"  value={this.state.contactmethod || ''} onChange={this.handleChange} name="contactmethod">
    <option value='Email'>URL</option>
    <option value='Phone'>Phone</option>
    <option value="SMS">SMS</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Use the value attribute in the select tag

```
value={this.state.contactmethod || ''}
```

the solution is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a state property for the default option text in the constructor

   - Don't worry about the default option value
2. Add an option tag to the render function. Only show using state and ternary expression
3. Create a function to handle when an option was selected
4. Change the state of the default option value in this event handler function to null

   ```
   Class MySelect extends React.Component
   {
       constructor()
       {
           super()
           this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
           this.state = {
               selectDefault: "Select An Option"
           }
       }
       handleChange(event)
       {
           const selectedValue = event.target.value;
           //do something with selectedValue
           this.setState({
               selectDefault: null
           });
       }
       render()
       {
           return (
           <select name="selectInput" id="selectInput" onChange={this.handleChange} value= 
               {this.selectedValue}>
            {this.state.selectDefault ? <option>{this.state.selectDefault}</option> : ''}
               {'map list or static list of options here'}
           </select>
           )
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to add my two cents to this, using Hooks,

You can subscribe to props in the DropDown

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';

const DropDown = (props) => {
  const { options, isMulti, handleChange , defaultValue } = props;
  const [ defaultValueFromProps, setdefaultValueFromProps ] = useState(undefined)

  useEffect(() => {
    
    if (defaultValue) {
      setdefaultValueFromProps(defaultValue)
    }
  }, [props])
  
  const maybeRenderDefaultValue = () => {
    if (defaultValue) {
      return { label: defaultValueFromProps, value: defaultValueFromProps }
    } 
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Select 
        width='200px'
        menuColor='red'
        isMulti={isMulti} 
        options={options} 
        value={maybeRenderDefaultValue()}
        clearIndicator
        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default DropDown;
```

and then in the parent component either pass the initial value or changed value from state

```
<DropDown options={GenreOptions} required={true} defaultValue={recipeGenre === undefined ? recipe.genre : recipeGenre} handleChange={handleGenreChange}/>
```

Then if it's a fresh form (no default value) you won't have to worry since the useEffect will ignore setting anything

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useTheme } from 'next-themes';
import { find } from 'lodash';

const ProductSelect = ({
  loading,
  options,
  onSelect,
  value,
  handleChange,
  ...props
}) => {
  const findDefaultValueById = find(options, { value });

  if (value && !findDefaultValueById) {
    return 'Loading...';
  }

  const { theme } = useTheme();
  const isDarkMode = theme === 'light';
  const backgroundColor = !isDarkMode ? '#18181b' : 'white';
  const borderColor = !isDarkMode ? '#3f3f46' : '#d4d4d8';
  const textColor = !isDarkMode ? 'white' : '#18181b';
  const placeholderColor = !isDarkMode ? '#fff' : '#18181b';
  const selectedValueColor = !isDarkMode ? 'white' : '#18181b';

  const handleSelect = (selectedValue) => {
    if (selectedValue && onSelect) {
      onSelect(selectedValue.id || null);
    } else if (!selectedValue) {
      onSelect(null);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="z-50 relative">
      <AsyncSelect
        className={`bg-${backgroundColor} ${
          isDarkMode ? 'dark:bg-[#18181b]' : ''
        } w-full outline-none min-h-unit-12 rounded-large transition-colors motion-reduce:transition-none`}
        styles={{
          control: (baseStyles) => ({
            ...baseStyles,
            borderColor,
            backgroundColor: `bg-${backgroundColor}`,
            color: `!text-${textColor}`,
            fontSize: 'font-medium',
            boxShadow: 'none',
            paddingTop: 12,
            paddingBottom: 12,
            borderRadius: 14,
            borderWidth: 2,
          }),
          menu: (provided) => ({
            ...provided,
            backgroundColor,
            borderRadius: 12,
          }),
          option: (styles, { isFocused }) => ({
            ...styles,
            backgroundColor: isFocused ? borderColor : backgroundColor,
            color: isFocused ? textColor : textColor,
            borderRadius: 12,
            fontSize: 14,
          }),
          singleValue: (styles) => ({
            ...styles,
            borderRadius: 12,
            fontSize: 14,
            color: selectedValueColor,
          }),
          menuList: (styles) => ({
            ...styles,
            borderRadius: 12,
            paddingLeft: 12,
            paddingRight: 12,
          }),
          placeholder: (styles) => ({
            ...styles,
            color: placeholderColor,
          }),
        }}
        isClearable
        cacheOptions
        defaultOptions
        options={options}
        isLoading={loading}
        noOptionsMessage={() => (loading ? 'Loading...' : 'No options found')}
        loadingMessage={() => 'Searching...'}
        onChange={handleSelect}
        defaultValue={findDefaultValueById}
        {...props}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductSelect;

// USING. //

<ProductSelect
            loading={productsLoading}
            label="Product and code"
            ariaLabel="Product"
            name="profile.product"
            placeholder="Product"
            value={values.profile.product}
            onSelect={(product) => setFieldValue('profile.product', product)}
            options={allProducts}
            initialValues={values?.profile.product}
            handleChange={handleChange}
            error={
              errors && errors?.profile?.product && touched?.profile?.product
                ? errors?.profile?.product
                : undefined
            }
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select onChange={handleCountry} value={selectCountry}>
-------------------add this field----------------
          <option value="" disabled>
            Select a country
          </option>
-------------------add this field----------------          
         {data?.continent?.countries.map(({ name, code }) => (
            <option key={code} value={code}>
              {name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select value={ProductDetail["category"]["_id"]}   onChange={(e)=>handleProductData("categoryID", e.target.value)}  >
 <option >Select Category</option>
 {
   Categories ===null ? "" : 
   Categories.map( (item, index) => <option key={index} value={item["_id"]}>{item["name"]}</option> )
 }
</select>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

2022 example with Redux react with useSelector

As of 2022 there is a defaultValue option in react-select. Please note that if you are using getOptionLabel, and getOptionValue, you need to make your default value match those option params you set....

for example

```
const responder = useSelector((state) => state.responder)



<Select
              name="keyword"
              required={true}
              className="mb-3"
              styles={customStyles}
              components={animatedComponents}
              closeMenuOnSelect={true}
              options={keywords}
              defaultValue={responder ? responder[0]?.responder?.keyword?.map((el) => { return {title: el.title, _id: el._id}}): ""}
              getOptionLabel={({title}) => title}
              getOptionValue={({_id}) => _id}
              onChange={(_id) => setUpload({...upload, keyword: _id})}
              isMulti
              placeholder="select Keywords"
              isSearchable={true}
              errors={errors}
              innerRef={register({
                required: "Add your Keyword"
              })}
            />
```

rather than setting your defaultValue with {label: "this", value: "that}

I needed to set mine with defaultValue({title:"this", _id: "that"})

Answer (score -1):

```
<Input 
  type='select' 
   name='defaultproperty'
   id='propertyselect'      
    >  
                         <option 
                          key={id} 
                          value={item.propertyId}
                          id = {item.propertyName}
                          defaultValue = {orgPropertyId} 
                          selected={item.propertyId === orgPropertyId}
                         >
                          {item.propertyName}
                           </option>  
                ) 
            </Input>
```

use selected will serve the purpose of default value text

Answer (score -1):

i think you can use selected prop at  tag

```
         <select
            defaultValue={plan.name}
            className="select w-full max-w-xs text-gray-700 mt-4"
          >
            {plans.vps.map((i) => (
              <option
                selected={plan.name == i.name}
                key={i.name}
                className="p-2 border"
                value={i.name}
              >
                {i.name}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
```

Look at this `selected={plan.name == i.name}`
also take notice about value update `defaultValue={plan.name}`

Answer (score -2):

In react-select if you want to define for the custom label, try this.

```
  <Select
    getOptionLabel={({ name }) => name}
  />
```

Answer (score -3):

You can simply do this as:

In react-select, initial options value

```
const optionsAB = [
  { value: '1', label: 'Football' },
  { value: '2', label: 'Cricket' },
  { value: '3', label: 'Tenis' }
];
```

API giving only:

```
apiData = [
  { games: '1', name: 'Football', City: 'Kolkata' },
  { games: '2', name: 'Cricket', City: 'Delhi' },
  { games: '3', name: 'Tenis', City: 'Sikkim' }
];
```

In react-select, for `defaultValue=[{value: 1, label: Hi}]`. Use `defaultValue` like this example:

```
<Select
  isSearchable
  isClearable
  placeholder="GAMES"
  options={optionsAB}
  defaultValue={{
    value: apiData[0]?.games , 
    label: (optionsAB || []).filter(x => (x.value.includes(apiData[0]?.games)))[0]?.label
  }}
  onChange={(newValue, name) => handleChange(newValue, 'games')}
/>
```

You can use this in Java normal also.

Comment: i think its if use custom package ?