# react select not recognizing default value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have a react select component that isn't recognizing the default value option. 
The code looks like this:

```
renderPlans(){
        if(this.props.plans){
            let list =  this.props.plans.map(item=>{
                return ({label:item.description, value:item.id})
            });

            return(
                <Select
                    name= "tile-plans"
                    value= {this.state.selected}
                    classNamePrefix='react-select-container'
                    options={list}
                    defaultValue={list[0]}
                    onChange={(e) => { e ? this.setState({selected: e.value}) : this.setState({selected: ''}) }}
                />
            )
        }
    }
```

from everything I can find on its docs this is the format to give it. Basically I just want the first option to always be the default choice as there will be times when there is only 1 option and it doesn't make sense for someone to need to select a drop down. I also have a graph that's being loaded underneath so if an option is selected the graph won't load.

This isn't a duplicate question as I know you can do it like this:
`value= {this.state.selected ? this.state.selected:list[0].label}`
but it's not working. The input remains blank on load.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a default value in react-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495696/how-to-set-a-default-value-in-react-select)

Comment: this isn't a duplicate of that question. I'm not trying to figure how to put a static string in the values section or placeholder data. I need an initial selection of the first choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation states that "If you don't provide these props, you can set the initial value of the state they control", referencing among others the `value` prop you provide.

You can set the `selected` to the first element in `list` when the component is created instead.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selected: this.props.list[0]
  };

  handleChange = selected => {
    this.setState({ selected });
  };

  render() {
    const { selected } = this.state;

    return (
      <Select
        value={selected}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={this.props.list}
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App
    list={[
      { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
      { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
      { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
    ]}
  />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Think you need `this.setState({selected: selectedOption });` . demo doesn't allow change displayed otherwise

Comment: @charlietfl Ops, thanks. I tried to be clever and match the variable names, but forgot one of them.

Comment: I whole heartedly understand why this should work and with the mod about it does work in sandbox. BUT not in actual code. I even tried the minimum of value={"hi"} to see if it would just spit that out and I still get a "Select..." placeholder text in the select on load.

Comment: @KyleT Could you create a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) isolating the wrong behavior you are experiencing? It will be easier to help you that way.

Comment: played around with your code in sandbox and was able to figure it out. Thanks Tholle, you've been a lifesaver today.