# react select is not picking up my selected value using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I am sorry if my question is silly, I am fairly new to Reactjs,

Please do not tell me to useHooks as I can't use it in my current project.

I am working on a form and on it's validations.

my relevant code:

```
//part of my state
    this.state = {
      form: {
        country: null,
        zipCode: "",
      },
      formErrors: {
        country: null,
      },
      countryList: Array<string>(),
    };
  }

       <Select name="country" defaultValue={countryOptions[1]}  options={countryOptions} value={form.country} onChange={(e) => {
                      this.handleCountryChange({value : e.value, label: e.value })
                    }}
    
                    />
                    {this.state.formErrors.country && (
                      <span className="err">{this.state.formErrors.country}</span>
                    )}

    
    
     handleCountryChange(e : countrySelection){
        const selectedCountry = e.value;
        console.log(selectedCountry);
        var formAux = { ...this.state };
        formAux.form.country = selectedCountry;
      
      }
```

but sadly my select keeps looking like this:[image]

Even after I pick a country and I can see it with the console log above. What is missing here in order for the select to pick up the value?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this something like this

[How to set a default value in react-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495696/how-to-set-a-default-value-in-react-select)

Here they did not use `defaultValue` property

As well as check other properties which they used.

As well as refer this answer of this question too

[react select not recognizing default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51754700/react-select-not-recognizing-default-value?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the state correctly, you can not mutate the state like that. You need to use `setState` API. See docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

In your case the event handler should be like this:

```js
 handleCountryChange(e : countrySelection){
    const selectedCountry = e.value;
    // you said this works correctly
    console.log(selectedCountry); 
    this.setState(currentState => ({
        // spread the entire state so that other keys in state remain as they are
        ...currentState,                
        form: {
            // spread state.form so that other keys in state.form remain as they are
            ...currentState.form,  
            // only update state.form.country     
            country: selectedCountry
        }
    }));
 }
```

Please read the code comments, that should help you understand.